# perl unexpected token in regex?

Tags: regex, perl, pipe

I've a unix process spitting out strings which needs to be surrounded with quotes and `,`'s. Perl was my favorite language sometime ago so I decided to use perl in combination with a pipe. The proces can be mimicked by a `cat` (i think). And I tried:

```
cat lines.txt | perl -pe s/(\w+)/,\'$1\'/
```

Which gives `syntax error near unexpected token '('` conform the error in the real life scenario
lines.txt looks like:

```
A
B
C
D
```

What's wrong?

Comment: You mean  `perl -pe "s/(\w+)/,'\$1'/"` ?

Comment: Thanks! if you make it an answer I can reward some points.

Comment: [Useless use of cat.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat)

Comment: *"The proces can be mimicked by a cat"* Are you saying it's so simple, even a cat can do it?!

Comment: @Borodin that's Schrödinger's cat, you don't know what is in the file unless you cat it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A suitable `perl` command can be this:

```
perl -pe "s/(\w+)/,'\$1'/"
```

We need to escape `$` to avoid shell trying to interpret `$1`.

Comment: You "don't need grep"? More like "you can't use grep".

Comment: made a typo in the question should have been `cat lines.txt | perl -p`.. But the answer remains very valid.

Comment: @drjerry: Sure, I didn't mean the question - the answer was a bit misleading, though. But it's corrected now so it's all good :)

Answer (score 2):

That error is from bad escaping. You also used `grep` when you meant to use `perl`, and you invovled `cat` where it wasn't needed.

```
perl -pe"s/(\w+)/,'\$1'/" lines.txt
   -or-
perl -pe's/(\w+)/,'\''$1'\''/' lines.txt
```